# Why Tao's Analysis introduce a direct sum $(f\oplus g)(x)=(f(x),g(x))$ to prove something about continuity?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

In Tao's *Analysis II*, the "Continuity and Product Space" chapter, he introduced an operation, which is uncommon in other books, called a **direct sum**, as in the figure. [image]

And then, he proved that

- the addition function "plus"($+$): $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$
- the subtraction function "minus"($-$): $(x,y)\mapsto x-y$
- the multiplication function "times": $(x,y)\mapsto x\cdot y$
- the maximum function: $(x,y)\mapsto \max(x,y)$
- the minimum function $(x,y)\mapsto \min(x,y)$

are all continuous function from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$.

Then he stated a theorem:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $f,g:X\to\Bbb R$. Then if $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $c\in X$, then $f+g,f-g,f\cdot g,\max(f,g),\min(f,g):X\to\Bbb R$ are all continuous at $c$.

His proof, take $f+g$ case for example, went by: since $f\oplus g:X\to\Bbb R^2$ is continuous at $c$, and $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ is continuous, so the composite function of $(f\oplus g)$ and $+$, $$\begin{alignat*}{2}
&+\circ (f\oplus g)\\
=&x\mapsto +((f\oplus g)(x))\\
=&x\mapsto +((f(x),g(x)))\\
=&x\mapsto f(x)+g(x)\\
=&f+g\end{alignat*}$$
the last is what we want, is continuous at $c$.

**My question:** It seems it can be more direct and natural to prove this theorem by a similar theorem in one-variable anaylsis, that is $\lim_{x\to c}(f+g)(x)=\lim_{x\to c}f(x)+\lim_{x\to c}g(x)$, with a little modify to the metric space cases. And then it can quite easily be made to derive that the continuity  case also hold. So why Tao didn't follow this way and he chose to define a rarely seen terminlogy direct sum (in analysis)? Is Tao's way more general or the theorem more strong to use in particular circumstances? Or are these often used in the more advanced courses?

Comment: Tao's way is the same as it is done usually, just a bit more formal, algebraic, and precise. He decouples the proof for continuity of $f+g$ into two ideas: continuity of $(f,g)$ and continuity of addition of reals. Thus, we obtain not only a proof for $f+g$, but also two another proofs, which we can reuse for other proofs. This may seem somewhat redundant for such simple examples, but the technique of breaking the proof into small, self-contained parts is ubiquitously powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that it might seem "un-necessary" to introduce less-elementary ideas to prove that the sum of continuous functions is continuous, but there are several reasons to do so, looking forward.

First, the general notion of continuity (that inverse images of opens are open) applies far beyond merely metric spaces, and/but then it becomes awkward to imitate the more elementary-looking argument that succeeds in metric spaces.

Second, when it comes time to prove that sums of *measurable* functions are measurable, the same form of argument (using direct sums of functions) succeeds!

Third, although many standard elementary analysis sources do not use direct sums, it is a correct application of the idea, is consonant with other notions of direct sum, and really is exactly the right thing to do. And, after all, in less elementary analysis there are direct sums everywhere.